# How to use the same foreach code for 2 collections?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 collections of 2 different types but have almost the same set of fields.
in one function, I need to iterate through one of the collections depending on one condition.
I want to write only one code block that will cover both cases.
Example:
I have the following code:

```
if (condition1)
{
    foreach(var type1var in Type1Collection)
    {

    // Do some code here
       type1var.Notes = "note";
       type1var.Price = 1;
    }
}
else
{
    foreach(var type2var in Type2Collection)
    {

    // the same code logic is used here
       type2var.Notes = "note";        
       type2var.Price = 1;
    }
}
```

Now: I want to simplify this code to use the same logic only once ( as they are identical ), something like the following ( P.S : I know the following code is not correct, I am just explaining what I want to do ):

```
var typecollection = Condition1 ? Type1Collection : Type2Collection;

foreach(var typevar in TypeCollection)
{

   // the same code logic is used here
   typevar.Notes = "note";
   typevar.Price = 1;       
 }
```

The definition of Type1 & Type2 is similar to the following code ( Actually they are Entity objects):

```
    public class Type1 : EntityObject
    {
        public int Type1ID { get; set; }
        public int Type1MasterID { get; set; }

        public String Notes { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type2 : EntityObject
    {
        public int Type2ID { get; set; }
        public int Type2MasterID { get; set; }

        public String Notes { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Update 1:

I have included some sample code I am using inside foreach block ( I am accessing a public properties of the 2 types).

Update 2:

I have included sample Type1 & Type2 definitions, as you can see I have 2 common Public Properties in both classes which I want to update in foreach block.

Update 3:

I am sorry for the confusion, Type1 & Type2 are derived from EntityObject ( They are both part of my entity model, and the Type1Collection & Type2Collection are actually EntityCollection of these 2 entities.

Comment: can you include two sample type definitions in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given Jon Skeet's hint of using LINQ's `Concat` method and the OP's statement that the classes involved are `EntityObject`s, here's another possible solution. This assumes that the `EntityObject` subclasses are defined as **partial** classes:

```
public partial class Type1 : EntityObject
{
    public int Type1ID { get; set; }
    public int Type1MasterID { get; set; }
    public String Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public partial class Type2 : EntityObject
{
    public int Type2ID { get; set; }
    public int Type2MasterID { get; set; }

    public String Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

This allows the OP to declare an interface with the common properties, and have his `EntityObject` subclasses implement that interface:

```
public interface IMyType
{
    String Notes { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public partial class Type1 : IMyType {}
public partial class Type2 : IMyType {}
```

And the original code becomes:

```
var query = (
    from type1var in type1Collection
    where condition1
    select (IMyType)type1var
   ).Concat(
    from type2var in type2Collection
    where !condition1
    select (IMyType)type2var
   );
foreach(var myType in query)
{
    myType.Notes = "note";
    myType.Price = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use dynamic. Note you will lose type safety.

```
var list1 = new List<bool>(){true,false};
var list2 = new List<int>(){1,2};

var typecollection = condition1 ? list1.Cast<dynamic>() : list2.Cast<dynamic>();
foreach (var value in typecollection)
{
    //then you can call a method you know they both have
    Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

Or if they share a common interface you can cast directly to that. You will maintain type safety

```
var list1 = new List<bool>(){true,false};
var list2 = new List<int>(){1,2};

var typecollection = condition1 ? list1.Cast<IConvertible>() : list2.Cast<IConvertible>();
foreach (IConvertible convertible in typecollection)
{
    //we now know they have a common interface so we can call a common method
    Debug.WriteLine(convertible.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Though I find your solution interesting, I still prefer compile-time safety.. Instead of using dynamic programming for your example (where ToString is a method from the object class), you could use covariance (using a variable of type IEnumerable<object>)

Comment: @DanielCastro my second solution has compile time safety

Comment: Still would suggest using IEnumerable rather than the List directly, if the only purpose is reading. Using a List would you allow to accidentally add an incompatible element, and you'll probably notice it only until runtime.

Comment: @DanielCastro I am using IEnumerable. that is what Cast returns. I only added the two lists at the top to make it compilable code.

Comment: I have tried to use the two examples you provided, but in both cases when I am accessing some public properties from type1 & type2, it is saying that it doesn't contains a definition for that field.

Comment: I will update the question with some logic I am using in the 2 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Predicate and Action stored in a Dictionary. I am suggesting Action here since the code snippet doesn't seems to return anything

```
public class IterationExample
{
    private readonly Dictionary<bool, Action> dictionary;

    public IterationExample()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<bool, Action> { { true, CollectionOneIterator }, { false, CollectionTwoIterator } };
    }

    public void PublicMethod()
    {
        dictionary[condition]();
    }

    private void CollectionOneIterator()
    {
        foreach (var loopVariable in Type1Collection)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }

    private void CollectionTwoIterator()
    {
        foreach (var loopVariable in Type2Collection)
        {
            //Your code here
        }

    }
}
```

With this way the readbility and testability of your code improves and also avoids long methods.

Edit:

```
public class Entity
{
    public IList<string> Type1Collection { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Type2Collection { get; set; } 
}

public class ConsumingClass
{
    public void Example()
    {
        var entity = new Entity();
        entity.PublicMethod();
    }
}

public static class IterationExample
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<bool, Action<Entity>> dictionary;

    static IterationExample()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<bool, Action<Entity>> { { true, CollectionOneIterator }, { false, CollectionTwoIterator } };
    }

    public static void PublicMethod(this Entity entity)
    {
        dictionary[condition]();
    }

    private static void CollectionOneIterator(Entity entity)
    {
        foreach (var loopVariable in entity.Type1Collection)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }

    private static void CollectionTwoIterator(Entity entity)
    {
        foreach (var loopVariable in entity.Type2Collection)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The types I am using are actually Entity Objects, I believe I can't modify modify the classes as you mention.

Comment: @AdelKhayata you can use extension method to overcome this, please refer my updated answer

Comment: Having the same code in two separate methods (`CollectionOneIterator` and `CollectionTwoIterator`) does not address the original problem of having the same code duplicated in two places.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base type for type1 and type2 that groups the common properties between the two classes:

```
class MyBaseType {
   // Common properties
}

class Type1 : MyBaseType {
   // Specific properties
}

class Type2 : MyBaseType {
   // Specific properties
}
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyBaseType> collection;
if(condition1)
   collection = type1Collection;
else
   collection = type2Collection;

foreach(MyBaseType element in collection) {
   // Common logic
}
```

EDIT:
As Simon points out in the comments, you should use an interface instead of a base type if it's enough (i.e you don't need a specific implementation for both types).

Comment: please dont use a base type when an interface will suffce

Comment: @Simon Right, just we are not sure if a base class is good for this case because we don't have enough information. But, again, you're right: if an interface is enough, that's the way to go

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very nice way to do it, but it would atleast work.

```
        var type1Collection = new Collection<Type1>();
        var type2Collection = new Collection<Type2>();

        var condition1 = new Random().Next(0, 2) != 0;

        dynamic selectedCollection;
        if (condition1)
            selectedCollection = type1Collection;
        else
            selectedCollection = type2Collection;

        foreach (var typeVar in selectedCollection)
        {
            typeVar.Notes = "note";
            typeVar.Price = 1;
        }
```

Comment: When I try your solution, I get the following error: Error 44 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' because 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody else has suggested an extension method yet:

```
public interface IMyType
{
    String Notes { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public static class MyTypeExtensions
{
    public static void MyLogic(this IMyType myType)
    {
        // whatever other logic is needed
        myType.Notes = "notes";
        myType.Price = 1;
    }
 }
```

Now, your original types just need to implement `IMyType`:

```
public class Type1 : IMyType
{
    public int Type1ID { get; set; }
    public int Type1MasterID { get; set; }

    public String Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Type2 : IMyType
{
    public int Type2ID { get; set; }
    public int Type2MasterID { get; set; }

    public String Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then the original code becomes:

```
if (condition1)
{
    foreach (var type1 in type1Collection)
    {
        type1.MyLogic();
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (var type2 in type2Collection)
    {
        type2.MyLogic();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for an extension method here at all. Once you've got the interface, you can just iterate over whichever collection you want, using each value as the interface. Of course, we don't know whether the OP is able to change the entity types.

Comment: True, but the extension method allows for keeping all the assignments in one place (along with any other code that the OP elided in the interests of readability).

Comment: I'd prefer to use `Concat` from LINQ to allow for just one loop, with the logic in one place - where that place is right where you're doing the work.

Comment: I have updated the question with how the 2 types are actually 2 EntityObjects, does this solution still useful in this case?

Comment: I hadn't even thought of using `Concat`, @JonSkeet . Nice!

Comment: @AdelKhayata, I've posted another solution (given Jon Skeet's big honking hint) that I believe answers your question better.